# angular reactive forms and button disabling/enabling

Tags: angular

I am using below code in component.html

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!projectForm.valid"
                    (click)="updateProjects()">Update</button>
```

Component.ts code is below

```ts
  this.projectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z1-9, _-]+$')]),
      ProjectID: new FormControl({ value: 'SQ123', disabled: true }),
      ProjectTypeID: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true}),
      ProjectSubTypeID: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true}),
      LifecycleTemplate: new FormControl('Plan', [Validators.required]),
      ConstructionTypeID: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
      ContractTypeID: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
      StartDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      StartDateSub: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      EndDate: new FormControl(''),
      EndDateSub: new FormControl(''),
      ProjectAddress: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
      Description: new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.projectForm.controls['StartDateSub'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.validateStartandEndDataSub();
    });
    this.projectForm.controls['EndDateSub'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.validateStartandEndDataSub();
    });
```

while using the `this.validateStartandEndDataSub();` function update button is not enabling due to `this.validateStartandEndDataSub();`
how to resolve the error to enable update button after filling all the values

```ts
  validateStartandEndDataSub() {
    const startDate = this.projectFormControls['StartDateSub'].value;
    const endDate = this.projectFormControls['EndDateSub'].value;
    if (endDate) {
      if (startDate > endDate) {
        this.projectFormControls['EndDateSub'].setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
      } else {
        this.projectFormControls['EndDateSub'].setErrors({'incorrect': false});
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `validateStartandEndDataSub` function?

Comment: please check added at the end of the question

Comment: write a custom validator function (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) instead of doing this routine. work within the framework instead of coding around it.

Comment: @bryan60, is it possible to create custom validators with multiple controls(startdate, end date)

Comment: yes, add it at the formgroup level. you then have access to all controls within the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a custom validator and add it at the form group level:

```
export function startBeforeEndValidator(startProp, endProp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const startCtrl = control.get(startProp);
    const endCtrl = control.get(endProp);
    const start = startCtrl ? startCtrl.value : null;
    const end = endCtrl ? endCtrl.value : null;
    return (start && end && start > end) ? {endBeforeStart: true} : null;
  };
}
```

then just register it like any other validator with your from group and the control properties as arguments.